# Wiring An RV, AC/Generator/24v DC existing

Tags: electrical, wiring

Woo here I go.
Wiring up an RV as a type of Mobile Office.
Need to run:
6 High performance computers that can draw ~500 watts each, 3000 watts total
6 32" TV Screens, ~20 watts each 120 Watts total
13,500 BTU "Power Saver" 120V AC that claims 1100-1300 Watts running

The RV is wired as a 24 Volt system. 2 huge 8d style batteries:
2 of these 12v https://www.interstatebatteries.com/products/8d-xhd linked together to form 24 Volts.
These batteries have 380 Reserve Capacity (RC)@25 Amps each

An Equalizer joins the 2 together: http://www.vanner.com/brochures/Battery-Equalizer-PB-6-01.pdf

So...so many options. I know I need a generator. 
I'm looking at 6500 max/5000 running watts inverter powered generator:
https://www.briggsandstratton.com/na/en_us/product-catalog/generators/portable-generators/q6500-quietpower-series-inverter-generator.html

The computers and TVs are obviously sensitive and need clean power in.

Now..do I run something off the 2 RV batteries? I'd like to get 5 hours or so. Can the generator charge the batteries as they're powering something?
a)the computers so would need inverter(s) to go from 24v DC to 120AC? ~3000watt draw
b)The Air conditioner? ~1100 watt draw
Have to take into consideration power loss from the inverter(s)

What's the deal with grounding this RV so I don't electrocute people?
What type of wire/conduit is safe for adding the 120v outlets? I hear stranded, maybe 14 gauge romex? Still would need some type of conduit I think?

Any other advice/help? 
Thanks?

Comment: Will you want to run this setup off of shore power instead of the generator at times?

Comment: Yes whenever possible

Comment: What does the RV already have for AC power?

Comment: Zero AC power now

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. You're asking about multiple issues (power, grounding, design); you might get better responses if you split it up into multiple questions.

Comment: Can you get 24VDC power supplies for the computers?